# Is {{each}} helper context differ in input values?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using emebr-1.0.pre.js

Having doubt in each helper context, below the following code for the reference. In the output UI title replaces "book1" and "book2" but the input fields are empty.

My doubt is which context is used in each helper, within {{each}} helper 'this' refers what??

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});


App.Book = Ember.Object.extend({
   title : null,
  author : null
 });
```

BooksController.js

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content : [
                App.Book.create({title : "Book1", author : 'author1'}),
                App.Book.create({title: 'Book2', author : 'author2'})
               ]           
});
```

BooksListView.js

```
 App.BooksView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName : "books_list",
  controllerBinding : "App.BooksController"
})
```

Handlebars

```
{{#each content}}
   <label>{{this.title}}</label>
   {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="this.author"}}
{{/each}}
```

The JSFiddle [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmPLF/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `BooksListView` has a `controllerBinding` set to `App.BooksController`.

It should be to something like `App.booksController`, because you want to bind it to an instance instead of a class:

```
App.booksController = App.BooksController.create();

App.BooksListView = Ember.View.extend({
   controllerBinding: "App.booksController"
});
```

About the `{{each}}` context, `this` refer to the current object, so this work as expected. Except that you don't should use `{{this.aproperty}}` on the `{{each}}` helper, just write `{{aproperty}}`:

```
{{#each content}}
  <label>{{title}}</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="author"}}
{{/each}}
```

[And here is the JSFiddle which works](http://jsfiddle.net/wemhr/). I have intentionally added `{{this}}` in order to let you see on which object it refers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply...! Don't mistake me. Could you please tell me the reason for don't  use  {{this.aproperty}} in each helper? Because before the ember.pre.1.0, I was using {{this.aproperty}} in {{each}} helper, it was working.....Anyway inside the each helper, 'this' refers the current object then why dont use..?

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue or not, but the documentation says: `when looping over objects that do not have properties, {{this}} can be used to render the object`, so I think you could submit an issue because it works with simple `{{this.author}}`, but don't work with `{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="this.author"}}`